# mfcc for entire song are different from mfcc calculated for segments of the same song

Tags: python, mfcc, librosa

I calculated MFCC on a song of 30 seconds, with a frame size of 25ms and a hop size of 10ms, the sample rate is 22050

```
spectro=librosa.feature.melspectrogram(track[1], sr=sampleRate, n_fft=int(sampleRate*0.025), hop_length=int(sampleRate*0.01))
frames_mfcc=librosa.feature.mfcc(track[1], S=spectro, sr=sampleRate, n_mfcc=13)
```

Then, I did the same thing for a 1 second segment of the same song.
But when I search the coefficients of the short song inside the long song, with a sliding window, I never obtain a perfect or a quite perfect match.

What could be the problem? Did I miss something?

Comment: Impossible to answer without a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just dropped into this question, so try to answer.
First you need to go to frequency domain. That is done with fast-Fourier-transform. In your case there are 22050 points if you want them in terms of frequency, they must be defined in terms of time. So if you miss by one - because of rounding integers into binary representation... results can vary.